# How do I convert [Size]byte to string in Go?

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a sized byte array that I got after doing `md5.Sum()`.

```
data := []byte("testing")
var pass string 
var b [16]byte
b = md5.Sum(data)
pass = string(b)
```

I get the error:

> cannot convert b (type [16]byte) to type string

Comment: I'd like to point out that creating a password like that without any kind of salt is extremely insecure and a bad idea.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can refer to it as a slice:

```
pass = string(b[:])
```

Answer (score 53):

A little late but keep in mind that using `string(b[:])` will print mostly invalid characters.

If you're trying to get a hex representation of it like php you can use something like:

```
data := []byte("testing")
b := md5.Sum(data)

//this is mostly invalid characters
fmt.Println(string(b[:]))

pass := hex.EncodeToString(b[:])
fmt.Println(pass)
// or
pass = fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
fmt.Println(pass)
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/NDGofcwxE6)

Comment: Depends on how you print it.

Comment: @OneOfOne are you sure this is the correct way to it. I got this at the output when I run the playground script you provided.

`�+�QYI��O�+��Uu
ae2b1fca515949e5d54fb22b8ed95575
ae2b1fca515949e5d54fb22b8ed95575`

Comment: @NikhilWagh that is correct, the first print is gonna be the raw checksum, not print-friendly, the other 2 will be the checksum converted to hex.

Comment: Why does this `fmt.Println(string(b[:]))` prints "mostly invalid data" ?

Comment: This is the correct answer to receive a md5 hash string. Everything else is not helpful..
requires: `import "encoding/hex"`

Answer (score 14):

it can be solved by this

```
pass = fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
```

or

```
import "encoding/base64"
pass = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b[:])
```

this will encoding it to base64 string

Comment: This is the correct answer in many cases,  not the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that `[n]byte` means array and `[]byte` means slice!

Comment: Could you please explain why you use base64 here? The question does not mention base64.

Answer (score 8):

**Update 02/01/2023**

Per this, [unsafe: add StringData, String, SliceData](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53003), the `reflect.StringHeader` and `reflect.SliceHeader` may be deprecated in `Go 1.20`. And the `unsafe.StringData`, `unsafe.String`, and `unsafe.SliceData` will replace them, refer to [1.20 release note](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20)

> The `unsafe` package defines three new functions `SliceData`, `String`, and `StringData`. Along with Go 1.17's Slice, these functions now provide the complete ability to construct and deconstruct slice and string values, without depending on their exact representation.

```golang
func String2Bytes(s string) []byte {
    if s == "" {
        return nil
    }
    return unsafe.Slice(unsafe.StringData(s), len(s))
}

func Bytes2String(b []byte) string {
    if len(b) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return unsafe.String(unsafe.SliceData(b), len(b))
}
```

---

**Before Go 1.20**

```golang
func Bytes2StrImp(b []byte) string {
    sliceHeader := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    var s string
    sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    sh.Data = sliceHeader.Data
    sh.Len = sliceHeader.Len
    return s
}
```

The above solution converts the byte array to string through Pointer operation. The `string(b[:])` will do a new string object and copy data from the byte array to the string.

Benchmark result with `string(b[:])`

```golang
func Bytes2StrRaw(b []byte) string {
    return string(b[:])
}
```

```
BenchmarkBytes2StrRaw-12              275305142                4.40 ns/op
BenchmarkBytes2StrImp-12              1000000000               0.315 ns/op
```

---

Although there are some simple answers here, I want to give one more efficient solution

```golang
func Bytes2StrImp(b []byte) string{
    sliceHeader := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    sh := reflect.StringHeader{
        Data: sliceHeader.Data,
        Len:  sliceHeader.Len,
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&sh)) // go vet error possible misuse reflect.StringHeader
}
```

---

Comment: Care to explain what is happening there and why is it so much faster?

Comment: This code violates recommendations at https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer:

"In general, reflect.SliceHeader and reflect.StringHeader should be used only as *reflect.SliceHeader and *reflect.StringHeader pointing at actual slices or strings, never as plain structs. A program should not declare or allocate variables of these struct types."

Comment: `go vet` also complains about thi in current version, e.g. try in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/G6rRGp8jwtW

Comment: Correct code: https://play.golang.org/p/Lh28f4HF_W9

Comment: @RedowanDelowar, the answer was updated. Hope I make myself clearly

Answer (score 4):

Make a slice of it:

```
pass = string(b[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not for printing hex-encoded strings, but in the *general* case when the `[size]byte` array may contain invalid UTF-8 sequence(s), then according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863211/2962507) they can be converted into valid UTF-8 using

```go
s := string([]rune(string(b[:])))
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/7ONq75aa9fy):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    b := [1]byte{0xff}
    s := string(b[:])
    fmt.Println(s, []byte(s), utf8.Valid([]byte(s)))
    // Output: � [255] false

    s = string([]rune(string(b[:])))
    fmt.Println(s, []byte(s), utf8.Valid([]byte(s)))
    // Output: � [239 191 189] true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found these comments really unhelpful because they assume OP just wants a literal string of the []byte.... but if you were like me and need utf8 decoded bytes as a string you can use this:

```golang
import  "unicode/utf8"
func bytesToUtf8(b []byte) string {
    var myString = "";
    for i := 1; i <= len(b); i++ {
        r, _ := utf8.DecodeRune(b[i-1:i])
        myString += string(r)
    }
    return myString
}
var uselessBytes := []byte{123,34,...}
helpfulUtf8String := bytesToUtf8(uselessBytes)
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try

```html
b.decode("utf-8")
```

please let me know, is that help you or not?
***strong text***

Comment: No because it’s not Go.