# Converting byte array to hex format

Tags: go, hash, hex

I am hashing passwords using Sha256.Sum256 then I'm supposed to store the hashed password on the database, but what I get instead is a byte array instead of a hex value. I cannot do ("%x", hash) because that only works on fmt

Comment: _"I cannot do ("%x", hash) because that only works on fmt"_ I don't understand this. This works, and returns the hexa string representation: `fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte{1, 2}))`

Comment: You may also do: `hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])`, see [Why can not convert \[Size\]byte to string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040896/why-can-not-convert-sizebyte-to-string-in-go/28041357#28041357)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is "how do I make a string of the hexadecimal representation of the byte array"

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    password := "abc123"
    sum := sha256.Sum256([]byte(password))
    hexstring := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum)
    fmt.Println(hexstring)
}
```