# How to detect when bytes can't be converted to string in Go?

Tags: string, unicode, encoding, go, utf-8

There are [invalid byte sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) that can't be converted to Unicode strings. How do I detect that when converting `[]byte` to `string` in Go?

Comment: If your encoding is UTF-8: [`unicode/utf8.Valid`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#Valid)

Comment: Read http://blog.golang.org/strings -- the `string` conversion is just a byte-for-byte copy, and you'll run into the invalid UTF-8 when you `range` over the code points (or convert to a `[]rune`) and get 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character (spec'd [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)). None of that crashes, so you only need to check validity if it's independently important for your app (or if you plan to do something else that _will_ crash on bad utf8).

Comment: Here's a sample with invalid UTF-8: http://play.golang.org/p/6yHonH0Mae

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can, as Tim Cooper noted, test UTF-8 validity with [`utf8.Valid`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#Valid).

But! You might be thinking that converting non-UTF-8 bytes to a Go `string` is impossible. In fact, ["In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes"](http://blog.golang.org/strings); it can contain bytes that aren't valid UTF-8 which you can print, access via indexing, pass to `WriteString` methods, or even round-trip back to a `[]byte` (to `Write`, say).

There are two places in the language that Go does do UTF-8 decoding of `string`s for you.

- when you do `for i, r := range s` the `r` is a Unicode code point as a value of type `rune`
- when you do the conversion `[]rune(s)`, Go decodes the whole string to runes.

(Note that `rune` is an alias for `int32`, not a completely different type.)

In both these instances invalid UTF-8 is replaced with `U+FFFD`, the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) reserved for uses like this. More is in the spec sections on [`for` statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) and [conversions between `string`s and other types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type). **These conversions never crash, so you only need to actively check for UTF-8 validity if it's relevant to your application, like if you can't accept the U+FFFD replacement and need to throw an error on mis-encoded input.**

Since that behavior's baked into the language, you can expect it from libraries, too. `U+FFFD` is [`utf8.RuneError`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#pkg-constants) and returned by functions in `utf8`.

Here's a sample program showing what Go does with a `[]byte` holding invalid UTF-8:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []byte{0xff}
    s := string(a)
    fmt.Println(s)
    for _, r := range s {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
    rs := []rune(s)
    fmt.Println(rs)
}
```

Output will look different in different environments, but in the Playground it looks like

```
�
65533
[65533]
```